# cannot find library under /usr/local/lib

Tags: c++, cmake

when I use CMakeLists.txt with:

```
find_library(cryptoppV libcryptopp.a)
```

`target_link_libraries(${PROJenter code hereECT_NAME} ${cryptoppV})`

then i can find a library under /usr/local/lib,and make the C++ programe right and  got the right result.

but when i replace it with:

```
-- find_library(cryptoppV libcryptopp.a)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} cryptopp)
```

then i got the error message：

```
ld: library not found for -lcryptopp
```

why cmake do not link /usr/local/lib by default? did i do something wrong?

-- *add by aijinsong Oct 7, 2018 6:37 AM*

i'm in more confused. when the CMakeLists.txt was:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
find_package(Boost 1.58 REQUIRED thread)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}  Boost::thread)
find_library(cryptoppV libcryptopp.a)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${cryptoppV})
```

the compiler can find cryptopp/sha.h. but when the CMakeLists.txt was:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
## find_package(Boost 1.58 REQUIRED thread)
## target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}  Boost::thread)
find_library(cryptoppV libcryptopp.a)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${cryptoppV})
```

the error message was:

```
fatal error: 'cryptopp/sha.h' file not found
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
```

when the CMakeLists.txt was:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
find_package(Boost 1.58 REQUIRED thread)
## target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}  Boost::thread)
find_library(cryptoppV libcryptopp.a)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${cryptoppV})
```

the error message was still:

```
fatal error: 'cryptopp/sha.h' file not found
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
```

why i use cryptopp that the cmake ask me to link with library Boost::thread? i'm in more confused.

-- *add by aijinsong Oct 7, 2018 11:56 AM*

And if i use `g++ main.cpp -o main -lcryptopp`, i can get the right result. This shows that the library cryptopp has been installed correcttly, and g++ can find the library. why when i do it by make, it can't find the library?

-- ***add for KamilCuk start***

-- *add by aijinsong at Oct 7, 2018 3:27 PM*

when i make it by make VERBOSE=1, i got the following message:

`cd /Users/aijinsong/Documents/projects/com.aijs.cxx/bolochain/src && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.3/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/bolochain.dir/link.txt --verbose=1`

and the text in link.txt is:
  `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/bolochain.dir/main.cpp.o  -o bolochain /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib -lcryptopp /usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_atomic-mt.dylib`

this command cause the failure link but when i edit it like following, then c++ link command process very well:
  `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -g -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/bolochain.dir/main.cpp.o  -o bolochain /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib -lcryptopp /usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_atomic-mt.dylib`

just delete:
  `-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk`

I'm still working on this problem.

-- ***add for KamilCuk end***

Comment: "why CMake do not link /usr/local/lib by default?" - The error is from the **linker**, not from CMake. It is depended on your system configuration whether linkers searches `/usr/local/lib`  or not. See e.g. this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873516/shared-library-in-usr-local-lib-not-found.

Comment: Why do you search for a library as the name using only a static library file? I guess the library cryptopp.a has no configuration thus does not populate the interface include directories to the linked target or it's configuration is invalid And the error comes from the compiler not cmake. Run `make VERBOSE=1` or `cmake .. -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON` and inspect full make output and the compiler options with include paths to know what's going on.

Comment: `Boost::thread` is an IMPORTED target, which has not only a corresponded **library file**, but also the **include directories** (corresponded to Boost library). When link with the IMPORTED target, your executable not only links with a Boost library, but also has the Boost include directories added. Luckily, these include directories contains headers for `cryptopp` library. See more about IMPORTED targets in [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets).

Comment: @KamilCuk please read the message i added for you in the question body

Comment: What's the point of all the `add for XXX` sections? If those are in response to comments, you're doing it wrong. Your question should be self-contained and one single entity, not the record of a discussion. That said, can you compile and link with the library from the commandline, without cmake? Further, please extract a [mcve] (C++ code and cmake-file).

Comment: Where is `cryptopp/sha.h` ? Just fix it with `string(APPEND CMAKE_C_FLAGS " -L<path to cryptopp dir>")`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for your suggestion. I'm bad using of stackoverflow. There was so many different type of questions in one single entity. And all the responses are so helpful that I'm in trouble to choose the 'right' one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist, Thanks @Kamil Cuk. The argument -VERBOSE=1 was so useful that I can get more detail messages that show me what happens when I use make.

The point is that when I use cmake under OSX system. It will generate a txt be named 'link.txt' which includes commands and part of it is as the following:
`-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk`

when I delete this part, the commands will execute right. but when I add this line, the commands execute wrong. so the point is that this line maybe limited the search path of c++. Thanks @tsyvarev . You are right, `-isysroot` limited the c++ linkers searches `/usr/local/lib`.

Second, I did't find out how to remove the line `-isysroot ...` generated by OSX cmake. So， I need to find another solution.

When I search more information about find_package/include_directories/target_link_libraries, I found out that find_package need a FindXXX.cmake file to help it to find out the header file and libraries of the target. So I googled a FindCyptoPP.cmake file. and in this file it find out tow vars, one hold the value of cryptopp's header directory path, and one hold the value of cryptopp's library path. Then I use include_directories/target_link_libraries as following, the problem 
war solved.

```
find_package(CryptoPP)
include_directories(${CRYPTOPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CRYPTOPP_LIBRARIES})
```

and then when I use `make -VERBOSE = 1`, I fond that the output was a little different when I use the CMakeLists.txt as following:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} cryptopp)
```

When I use three lines, the output contains a line `/usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.dylib`. When I use one line, the output contains a line `-lcryptopp`.

So, with the command line `-isysroot`, the command line `-lcryptopp` will search library under the directory defined by `-isysroot`, and under the directory, there is no library named `cryptopp` but under `/usr/local/lib`. But with command line `/usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.dylib`, it gaves the absolute path of the library, so the linkes just do the linking task and need not search. Thanks @Kamil Cuk again.

Thrid, I knew include_directories/target_link_libraries are two separate steps which one is used for include header file and one is used for link libraries.

Still, there were some problems not soled:
- how to remove -isysroot?
- how to create a FindXXX.cmake file?
- how to make `/usr/local/lib` as a default search directory and was it a practice way to do so?

I will continue working on them, and come back a few days or weeks later.